# xval get message from resource file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, resources, xval

I'm working on a CMS system which uses a resource file to get information and errormessages from. The client side validation is working without problems, only it's not getting the errormessage from the resource file. While debugging i figured out xval seems to get the errormessages from a javascript file where the messages are set hard-coded. Is there some way to override this?

Below the code which should make the relation to the resourcefile en specify the error when the field is left empty.

```
[Property]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(CMSMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "EnterValidMoney")]
    public virtual Double ShippingCost { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

xVal comes with a bunch of message JS files (in the Optional/Internationalization folder) but there appears to be no documentation on how to use them!

It looks like you simply need to include a <script src="..."> block after the min library is inluded.

Comment: i'm aware of that, i just upgraded from version 0.8 to 1.0 and saw they were new. But i didn't implement them, so these JS files aren't used.

Comment: You could create your own handler (ASHX or JS response MVC action) that emits the strings from your resource files in the same JS format and reference that instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Gave me an idea to try something with an old customwritten js resourcefile a colleque written a few months ago :-)

Comment: I indeed can use the JS files as resources. But what i want is to use .NET resource files (.resx) Any idea how i can reference those? Or override the standard JS resources which are being used?

Comment: I meant that you could emit your own JS fle that is generated on the server-side on demand (though caching would be a good idea) by an ASP.NET HTTP handler which extracts the data from your existing standard .NET assembly resource file(s).  Alternatively, this could be done by a batch application that generated the JS file whe the site is deployed.